# Wix Editor: How do you set manually the size of the container box in Wix Editor? & Underline link on hover only

Tags: velo

Hi I am building a website on Wix, and have these two burning questions:

**Q1:** How do you set manually the size of the container box in Wix Editor?
Up until now, I have resized the container box by dragging it, but now I need a pixel-perfect box, and I would like to set the size manually (type it in), but I cannot find this option in the Wix editor. Is there a functionality for that?

**Q2:** How to underline a link on hover only?
Also, I want to keep underlining a link text on hover only. Is there a functionality for that?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.